# Laravel 5 after 3 posts show an add

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hello guys i have declared my posts with variable `$lastItems`

```
@if($lastItems->total() > 0)                   
  @foreach($lastItems as $item)
     @include('._posting.items')                                                  
  @endforeach                                    
@else
     @include('errors.emptycontent')
@endif
```

and i want to add ads after each 3 post,  i use something like this

```
@if($lastItems->total() > 0)                   
  @foreach($lastItems as $item)
     @include('._posting.items')                                                  
  @endforeach  
 @if($item = 3)
    <img src="link" alt="ads">
 @endif                                  
@else
     @include('errors.emptycontent')
@endif
```

but the problem is, when i try like this it shows the ads after every post not after 3 posts.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you might wanne take a closer look at `@if($item = 3)`

Comment: you mean with "=" to "==" ?

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like:

```
@if($lastItems->total() > 0)                   
  @foreach($lastItems as $key => $item)

     @include('._posting.items')

     @if (($key + 1) % 3 == 0)
         <img src="link" alt="ads">
     @endif                                                  
  @endforeach                                 
@else
     @include('errors.emptycontent')
@endif
```

Comment: that did the trick, but at 3 first posts it counts +1, so i receive it after 4-th post, after that is ok?

Comment: in this case, if $key starts in 0, you will show the first add after four items.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost same problem, in my case I had to change div's class. So I used sth like this and it helped me:

```
    <?php $var = -1; ?>
@foreach($lastItems as $item)
  <?php $var ++;?>
    @if($var%3 == 0 && $var!=0)
       @include('errors.emptycontent')
    else
        @include('._posting.items')
   @endif
@endforeach
```

I hope it helps :)